# What is the best way to manage a power app by team rather than co-owners?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

Can someone advise what is the best way to manage a power app by team rather than co-owners?

For example, a person A creates a PowerApps canvas app, but the ownership retains with him/her only; Though he/she can make others in the team as Co-Owners, Co-owners cannot delete the app.

So am looking to find a way where the PowerApps Canvas app is managed by team and all of them as Owners.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is Apps owned by a service account, though each option has its own merits & demerits - this is also a preferred option.

And the connection references used during deployment to higher environments will make the app owned by Deployment service account also.